# How can I compare cells to a variable that contains a number ? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have columns in Excel that I fill from other columns. I look for the specific ones using the clause ``WHERE`

- My column [Period] can be 0, 1, 2 or 3.
- I select one of those using the counter j that goes from 0 to 3, but when I do this `[Period]= j` , it doesn't work.

Here is my original code :

```
For j = 0 To 3
    For i = 1 To iMax
    If Worksheets("Results").Cells(i, 1) = "Extraction" And Worksheets("Results").Cells(i, 2) = "IDK" And Worksheets("Results").Cells(i, 3) = "DAOUI" Then
        Compteur = i
        Set RecT = gConnect.Execute("SELECT Sum([Volume]) FROM [Output$] WHERE ([Entity]=""TREATMENT FACILITIES"" AND [Period]= j) ;")
```

So I tried to convert j to a string, using this : `k = CStr(j)` before my loop, and then using `[Period]=k`, but still, it doesn't work.

Note that when I use `[Period]=0` it works perfectly. The error is specifically around the `j`..

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "j" must not be in the quotes as it is a variable. The query was reading "j" as the letter "j" before.

```
For j = 0 To 3
    For i = 1 To iMax
    If Worksheets("Results").Cells(i, 1) = "Extraction" And Worksheets("Results").Cells(i, 2) = "IDK" And Worksheets("Results").Cells(i, 3) = "DAOUI" Then
        Compteur = i
        Set RecT = gConnect.Execute("SELECT Sum([Volume]) FROM [Output$] WHERE ([Entity]=""TREATMENT FACILITIES"" AND [Period]= " & j & ") ;")
```